# Belgium Antwerp Police Immigration Index help

Tags: germany, belgium

I am trying to find more information about an ancestor whose name is listed in the Belgian Antwerp police immigration index, but only a name. I have a file number and a page number and an FHL film number, but it only is a list of names, and from what I've read about other people's searches on here there should be a file with more information?

Also, his whole family came over, I am not sure if it was exactly at the same time but they did all come, but I don't have records for them I'm the immigration index.

I'm not sure if there is anything more I can find out, but I'm hitting a bit of a wall as to where to look and how.

The details I have are:

```
Frank Otto Eichler
File number 56715
Page 71
FHN number 2234256
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has asked for it to be closed

Comment: Plese do not vandalise your posts in this manner.  You can delete your own post using the delete button below the text.

Comment: When, even if only approximate, do you think that Frank was born?

Comment: I realize OP asked for this to be closed, but just in case they are still interested, the full record 56715 (not just the index) is viewable at FamilySearch. It is for a _Frédéric_ Otto Eichler, born 3 March 1854 in "Merseburg (Saxe)" (probably [this place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merseburg)), occupation garçon d'hotel / de café. Parents appear to be Auguste Eichler (~1827) and Chérise Caladre (~1831). If OP wants the question reopened, an answer could be written to show how to find the full record from the information given.